# PHP Stop Remote File Download if it Exceeds 5mb

Tags: php

How do I stop a remote file from downloading a file if it exceeds 5mb? If I stop it while transferring, will the file be held somewhere in some other temp dir or memory? How would I know? Here is my current code:

```
$url = 'http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/archives/images/large/heic0601a.jpg';
$file = '../temp/test.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: As in, keep `file_get_contents` from retrieving files over 5MB?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There are a number of legitimate reasons for wanting to do this, but depending on your reasons it may not be necessary.

Comment: it doesn't matter what method is used :). I just need to be able to limit the download of the file and throw an error to the user saying "Your file is too big! please make sure it's smaller." like that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways in which you could do this, but because you are currently using `file_get_contents()`, here is what I would do:

- Open the remote file using `fopen()`
- Read the file and save it in increments using `fread()` - this allows you to track the current size and throw and error when you pass the threshold.

Something like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/archives/images/large/heic0601a.jpg';
$file = '../temp/test.jpg';
$limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

if (!$rfp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
  // error, could not open remote file
}
if (!$lfp = fopen($file, 'w')) {
  // error, could not open local file
}

// Check the content-length for exceeding the limit
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
  if (preg_match('/^\s*content-length\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*$/', $header, $matches)) {
    if ($matches[1] > $limit) {
      // error, file too large
    }
  }
}

$downloaded = 0;

while (!feof($rfp) && $downloaded < $limit) {
  $chunk = fread($rfp, 8192);
  fwrite($lfp, $chunk);
  $downloaded += strlen($chunk);
}

if ($downloaded > $limit) {
  // error, file too large
  unlink($file); // delete local data
} else {
  // success
}
```

NB: it is tempting to inspect the `Content-Length:` header before you receive any of the file to check whether the file is too large - you can still do this if you like, but do not trust the value! The header is essentially an arbitrary value, and while it would be a protocol violation to use a content length that does not match the size of the file, it could be used to fool the system into downloading a file that breaks the rules. You'd need count the bytes even if you do check this value.

You could also do this using curl via the data callback, but I would regard this as a less satisfactory solution, mostly because of fact that curl requires a string function name and not the standard generic `callable` type, which means you would either need to use a global variable or a `static` variable in order to keep track of the downloaded content length, neither of which are acceptable (IMHO) for this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Dave! :D, the code looks almost exactly what I was planning :)  I'll try it now...

Comment: This is the most robust solution. The cURL method described in my answer will only work if the requested server always returns the `Content-length` header, and there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: @webdev Added a `Content-Length:` header check before any data is downloaded for early error-out if file reported size is too large.

Comment: @DaveRandom yah I dont trust the header either ;) That's why i'm just using the header to check if the file is too big. If the header is successful then I read the file to make sure again it's not too big. That's my current setup :).

Comment: @DaveRandom your solution is hanging on remote files less than 5mb until it reaches a 30 second timeout :/  
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded..."

Comment: I approved the check on EOF, just in case the Content-Length header is not available (chunk-encoding HTTP 1.1).

Comment: @webdev Ahh crap. Sorry about that, was not fully paying attention evidently :S

Comment: @DaveRandom no prob. it happens. thanks again for your hard work Dave. Much appreciated ;)

Comment: Don't forget you need to `fclose($lfp);` before attempting to unlink the file otherwise it maybe locked.

Answer (score 2):

As for taking a URL and limiting the size, it's not too hard...but `file_get_contents` won't do it.  You could `fopen` the url, and use `stream_get_meta_data` on the stream to get an array of info about the stream.  If i'm reading the [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php#example-3828) right (and if the transfer encoding isn't "chunked"), you'll find the `Content-Length` header in there, which will tell you the file size.  If the value is set, and is over your limit, bail.

If the stream metadata doesn't have that info, or the info says the file's small enough, you still have the stream itself; you can still `fread` from the remote file and `fwrite` to the local one in chunks til you read it all or hit the limit.  Of course, if you get to that point, the file will still exist once you hit the limit; you'll have to delete it yourself.

Comment: Note also from the manual page for `stream_get_meta_data()` re: `unread_bytes`: "Note: You shouldn't use this value in a script."

Comment: @DaveRandom: You shouldn't *trust* that value in a script.  If it weren't meant to be *used*, it wouldn't be there.  :)

Comment: If only that were true. This is PHP, remember? :-P

Comment: Oh yeah.  I keep forgetting about that.  :)

Comment: yah, i'm still new to php downloading so I just grabbed that filegetcontents off the internet :). Yah Dave gave the example of fread. There's a curl example also. which is faster or does it matter?

Comment: @webdev What matters is a) what you find easiest and b) what is available on your server. Personally I think that the curl API makes this sort of thing messier than it needs to be, but YMMV. If I'm completely honest I wouldn't use either approach, I'd use raw sockets and an HTTP lib, either of my own devising or something like [Artax](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax) - but for your purposes that's probably overkill, and it requires a fairly intimate knowledge of HTTP.

Comment: Yah I think I'll stick with your php example :). I'm also checking the HTTP header for the file size but I dont want to be dependent on that since anyone can spoof the header info. I don't mind overkill :). I'm addicted to performance so please give me as much info as you can :)

Comment: @webdev Well I guess checking the http header at the start of the request would be OK for instantly *rejecting* the request ("the content is definitely too big") but not acceptable for *accepting* it. *however* I'm not certain that either curl or fopen let you get access to the headers until the request is complete - by which time you have downloaded the whole file anyway. Let me test it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with `file_get_contents` - you'll need to use the PHP cURL extension to grab the file size.

```
<?php
$max_length = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
$url = 'http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/archives/images/large/heic0601a.jpg';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data === false) {
  echo 'cURL failed';
  exit;
}
$contentLength = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}
echo "Content-Length: $contentLength\n";

if ($contentLength > $max_length) {
    echo "File is too large\n";
} else {
    echo "File size is ok\n";
}
```

Wrap this up in a function and use it to check a URL - anything too large can be skipped.

**Downside:**

This method only works if the `Content-Length` header is returned by the server - not all servers are well-behaved and not all will return a correct length.

**Upside:**

There's no need to download and write up to `$max_length` bytes. This method will be faster and less resource intensive.

Modified from:

http://php.net/filesize#92462

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on DaveRandom's solution along the same lines but without writing the file until it's completely loaded.

```
<?php
define('MAXMB', 5);
define('BYTESPERMB', 1048576);

$maxsize = MAXMB * BYTESPERMB;

$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = '';
$completed = true;
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $chunk = fread($handle, 8192);

  $size += strlen($chunk);
  if ($size > $maxsize) {
      $completed = false;
      break;
  }
  $contents .= $chunk;
}
fclose($handle);

if ($completed) {
  // File appears to be completely downloaded so write it --
  file_put_contents('path/to/localfile', $contents);

} else {
  // It was too big
}
```

Comment: ...why would you do this? You are just pointlessly consuming more memory than necessary by holding up to 5MB of data in memory ;-)

Comment: how does it check for the filesize without writing? is it being written in memory?

Comment: It's being read into the $contents variable, which is in memory.  Then only at the end is the variable being written out, and since the $completed variable is set to false if the size is exceeded, you can just skip that step and the memory will be disposed of by php.

Comment: also please note the `fread()` is not guaranteed to return the number of bytes specified by the `$length` argument, you need to check the `strlen()` of the downloaded content rather than blindly adding 8192 to the length on every iteration for safety

Comment: @DaveRandom It really depends on the specific use case, server platform, number of users etc.  On a server that is bottlenecked on IO, using RAM makes sense.  Since this looks like a spider activity to me, either solution makes sense, and fwiw I had already coded mine when I saw yours was posted a bit before mine.  I already credited yours as a solution along the same lines that will work.

Comment: but this is still good to know since writing to memory is blazing fast. But I wouldn't use this on a server with only 1gb of ram.

Comment: @webdev The speed of writes to memory vs disk is irrelevant here, because the bottleneck is going to be the speed of the network connection. /cc gview

Comment: @gview Don't get me wrong, I'm not having a pop, neither do I think you plagiarised my answer (there are a limited number of ways to do this) I'm just questioning your choice of storing in memory (feels a little micro-optimisation-y) but you are not wrong. In fact here, have a +1 :-)

Comment: no worries @DaveRandom, I adjusted my version to reflect your completely valid byte length point as well. All things considered, I'd probably use your solution.

Comment: yah i/o is irrelevant when my bandwidth is only 10mbps. but this is handy to know on high bandwidth servers :).

Comment: @webdev I would be *very* surprised if you would ever find a server setup where the network speed in *not* the bottleneck. Remember, you are limited by the slowest link in the chain - your connection can be as fast as you like, if the remote server is slow it's not relevant. Plus modern server HDDs are so fast they will make your eyes water, certainly *way* faster than the average server NIC.

Comment: when i said "my bandwidth" i meant "my server bandwidth" haha. sorry for typo ;). yah, these days the hard disks are like writing at 80MB/s .