# PHP Stop Reading Remote Files when after it is Fully Downloaded

Tags: php

I'm getting a 30 second timeout error because the code keeps checking if the file is over 5mb when it's under. The code is designed to reject files over 5mb but i need it to also stop executing when the file is under 5mb. Is there a way to check the file transfer chunk to see if it's empty? I'm currently using this example by DaveRandom:

[PHP Stop Remote File Download if it Exceeds 5mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963158/php-stop-remote-file-download-if-it-exceeds-5mb)

Code by [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom):

```
$url = 'http://www.spacetelescope.org/static/archives/images/large/heic0601a.jpg';
$file = '../temp/test.jpg';
$limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB

if (!$rfp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
  // error, could not open remote file
}
if (!$lfp = fopen($file, 'w')) {
  // error, could not open local file
}

// Check the content-length for exceeding the limit
foreach ($http_response_header as $header) {
  if (preg_match('/^\s*content-length\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*$/', $header, $matches)) {
    if ($matches[1] > $limit) {
      // error, file too large
    }
  }
}

$downloaded = 0;

while ($downloaded < $limit) {
  $chunk = fread($rfp, 8192);
  fwrite($lfp, $chunk);
  $downloaded += strlen($chunk);
}

if ($downloaded > $limit) {
  // error, file too large
  unlink($file); // delete local data
} else {
  // success
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far the way you're trying to use it.

Comment: im using the exact same code at DaveRandom's answer. it's the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963158/php-stop-remote-file-download-if-it-exceeds-5mb

Comment: I understand that, but it is good practice at SO to include the relevant portion of the code in this post so that this question can be understood on its own.

Comment: thanks Ian. ok i'll remember to post here next time dave :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check if you have reached the end of the file:

```
while (!feof($rfp) && $downloaded < $limit) {
  $chunk = fread($rfp, 8192);
  fwrite($lfp, $chunk);
  $downloaded += strlen($chunk);
}
```